# Should I accept the current job offer while waiting for another?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

Requesting your valuable advice.

I have done few internships. As of now, have one offer in Node.js (Internship to be converted to full time).
Timeline - To be confirmed by end of the day or tomorrow.

Also I'm about to appear, for a last round of interview for Spring Boot (Junior Level).
Timeline - Interview on 6th December

I'm neither good in JavaScript nor Java, but found Spring Boot more interesting than Node.js.

Now, I'm in a dilemma regarding the offer. If I accept this current offer, I may or may not like the work and will also loose a potential offer(which i do like).

But again, I'm an unemployed graduate student, who is desperately looking out for a job with minimal experience.

Both of these workplaces are initial stage startups.

Any advice or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add in your question what the timeline looks like. When do you have the interview, when do you need to give a response to the first offer, etc.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, updated the timeline.

Comment: Can you ask to push back the decision on the job offer until after the final interview?

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely up to YOU to either:

1. Accept the position that is currently offered to you.
2. Wait for the other potential offer in the hope that it comes to be.

There are risks associated with either choice that you need to consider.

My own philosophy is to "let your yes be yes and your no be no".  That means if you accept the first offer you should let the 2nd company know you have accepted another offer and are no longer available.  So regardless of where you are in that interview process, you end it.

If you really want the 2nd job, decline the first position and hope things work out as you want.  But, of course, there are no guarantees.  The 2nd company may turn you down and then you must keep looking.

You could also ask the first company for more time and it's my belief that honesty is the best here.  Just tell them why and perhaps use that to get them to "sweeten" the offer.  In this case you might say:

> The only thing holding me back from accepting it right now is the
> internship part of the offer.  If you could bring me on as a regular
> junior-level developer I could accept the offer now.

For one thing that may buy you some more time as they consider their position but it also may get you what you want now without having to wait on the 2nd company.

You might also use the fact that you have an offer to accelerate the process with the 2nd company.  You could say to them:

I've received an offer and I need to let them know by such-and-such a date.  My first preference would be the position we're discussing, so is there any way we can accelerate the process?"

Interviewing candidates is a lot of work for companies and losing a qualified candidate is not desirable.

I do feel, however, that accepting an offer only to later turn it down for anything other than an extreme situation is very unprofessional.  Bad decisions like that have a habit of coming back to bite you later in your career.  For example the people you "burned" end up being around you in a few years.  Most industries are "small" enough that you often encounter the same people again and again.

Comment: Alright, I shall be informing both the companies about it. I'll try to push the date by 6th or 7th December. But if they deny, then I would have no choice other than joining the first company. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that an actual job offer is always better than a future "maybe" offer.  You will learn a lot programming in Node.js and it's a marketable skill.  There is also nothing that says you cannot also learn Java/Spring Boot while you are working with Node.  The important thing is to gain experience.

Comment: While it is unfortunate and probably burns a bring, accepting and reneging on an offer is not uncommon in today's market. You can absolutely accept an offer and continue interviewing elsewhere. Exploding offers are hostile to workers and if companies are particularly concerned about reneging, then they should reconsider their policy. When you do decide to renege, you should be prompt about notifying them.

Answer (score -2):

You don't have to just accept things, you can try to steer things in the right direction for you. And when you have a problem like this, there is a systematic approach.

First, you can accept the offer with A. So that's your minimum. You don't want to use any strategy that gives you a worse result than "job with A".

Not responding to A and having an interview with B two weeks in the future is not a good strategy. It might very easily lead to getting nothing at all. What improves your chances is first talking to B: Tell them that you have an offer, that you would prefer an offer by them, and ask them to interview at an earlier time. And talk to A. Tell them that you are interviewing somewhere else, and ask how much time you have to accept. If you're lucky you manage to move the interview with B to be before the latest acceptance date with A. If not - see who was inflexible, and/or tried to put you under pressure, and you prefer a job with whoever was more flexible.